# Runtime Exception while with 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, runtimeexception

I wrote a class that has a 2d array that grows based on user input and allows user to enter numbers in array. The user would enter `2  2` for the size and `2 4 5 4` for the numbers It would print out like this

```
2 2 
2 2
```

It works until I enter an array size `7 1` , 7 rows and 1 column. I get an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Assignment7.main(Assignment7.java:55)
```

I don’t understand why

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment7 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 

    {




    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(" ");

    int [][] nums = new int[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()];


    System.out.print(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
        {

        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; ++j)

            {

            nums[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

            }           
        }           

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)

        {

            System.out.print("\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; ++j)

        {

            System.out.print(nums[i][j]);

         }

        }

    }               
}
```

Answer (score 3):

second dimension's length should be `nums[i].length`, Note:  (`i` for your example)

Answer (score 1):

For your inner loop, you're using the size of the outer array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; ++j)
```

This should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; ++j)
```